# Reuse images in articles with file_field_sources module

Tags: entities, media

I would like to reuse the already posted images in the articles of my blog.

I am using the core field_image in articles and when I installed the file_field_sources module, there were no options in my "content type -> manage fields" page.

Is this module able to use / extend the core field_image?

Answer (score 1):

IMCE is an image/file uploader and browser that supports personal directories and quota.
https://www.drupal.org/project/imce

Comment: Thank you for your time but I would like to reuse the images as a field in the field_image. If I just insert images in the content then the images can't be pulled in teasers.